# Apply restriction DML and DDL

Tags: sql, oracle, permissions

```
SELECT 
     D.OS_USERNAME
    ,D.terminal AS MACHINE
    ,D.OBJ_NAME
    ,D.ACTION_NAME
    ,D.timestamp
    ,D.Sql_Text 
FROM DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL D 
WHERE D.OWNER = 'HRADMIN' 
  AND D.ACTION_NAME LIKE '%INSERT%' 
  AND D.OS_USERNAME NOT IN ('MuhammadJav','zeeshankh1');
```

this query give me  record

I want to apply limit or restriction so that only `D.OS_USERNAME ('MuhammadJav','zeeshankh1','Alikh1')` can run insert,update,delete,alter statements but other user can't insert,update,delete,alter the data.

Comment: you have to give grant privilege

Comment: How to give  grant privilege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, the privilege to insert, update or delete are managed on the user or role level. Those users are database users, just like your `HRADMIN`.

If the operating systems users like MuhammadJav, zeeshankh1, Alikh1 use the same oracle account, things become much more difficult.

DML statements like 'ALTER' or 'CREATE' are handled totally different. A user like 'HRADMIN' can do what he/she wants with the tables and other objects in it's own schema. It is possible, but very difficult to prevent this.

So, the traditional solution is to give MuhammadJav, zeeshankh1, Alikh1 their own oracle accounts and grant them the privileges you want as user HRADMIN:

```
GRANT INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON HRADMIN.your_table_name TO MUHAMMADJAV;
GRANT INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON HRADMIN.your_table_name TO ZEESHANKH1; 
etc
```

Comment: Yes, after the GRANT statement, the users MUHAMMADJAV etc are able to insert, update and delete the table HRADMIN.your_table_name.

Comment: sir i mean if the user is not MUHAMMADJAV etc are able to insert, update and delete the table or (table data)

Comment: Only those Oracle users can insert into the table that have been granted the privilege. So, in the example above, MUHAMMADJAV and ZEESHANKH1 can insert, but ALIKH1can not insert (because there is has been no GRANT statement with his username=.

Comment: Because a user have multiple OS_name so i want restrict the  OS_name for example OS-name(Ali,ali1) Ali can  able to insert, update and delete the table or (table data) but ali1 can't and both have same user

Comment: Please have a look at [ALL_TAB_PRIVS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_TAB_PRIVS.html#GUID-F3265681-6114-45C2-BE79-99C8D0DD517E). The `GRANTEE` is "user or role to whom access was granted". Privs are inside the database, so apply certainly on the database level. If you want OS level, it's your job to map the OS users to a role. That is possible, but I would certainly not do that myself.

Comment: At my place of work, it is strictly forbidden that multiple OS users share the same personal database account. I believe the main reason is exactly the kind of problems you are trying to solve. I'm sure it is technically possible, but again, I wouldn't do it.